# Is it possible to use Qt VS Tools to work on a cross-platform project and have it automatically keep project changes synced in a .pro file?

Tags: qt, qt5, cross-platform

I am trying to understand what the intended workflow is when using Qt VS Tools to develop a cross-platform application. If I have per-platform options in the .pro file, does that mean that I must manually keep the .pro file in sync with the .vcxproj file when working on Windows not using Qt Creator?

For example, I have set up a test project and implemented a little desktop application using Qt VS Tools. I can now select "Create Basic .pro File" from the  Qt VS Tools extension menu. This will create the following .pro file which I can build and run from Qt Creator:

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = TestQt
DESTDIR = ../x64/Debug
QT += core gui widgets
CONFIG += debug
DEFINES += _UNICODE _ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE WIN64 QT_DLL QT_WIDGETS_LIB
INCLUDEPATH += ./GeneratedFiles \
    . \
    ./GeneratedFiles/$(ConfigurationName)
DEPENDPATH += .
MOC_DIR += ./GeneratedFiles/$(ConfigurationName)
OBJECTS_DIR += debug
UI_DIR += ./GeneratedFiles
RCC_DIR += ./GeneratedFiles

include(TestQt.pri)
```

Now say however I want to make the project have some platform-specific dependency. As an example say I add the following before "include(TestQt.pri)" in the above -- but this could be any kind of manual edit to the .pro file.

```
windows {
    SOURCES += WindowsSpecific.cpp 
}
```

This will work in Qt Creator but I would have to manually add the new file in Visual Studio. If I now add something platform agnostic in Visual Studio and rebuild the .pro file via the same extension menu item, I will lose anything that I manually added to the .pro file like the include of WindowsSpecific.cpp above.

So is the intention that I create a .pro file once and from then on manually edit the .pro file to keep it in sync with the Visual Studio project or is there some automatic way that I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no good way to do this.

A better workflow that solves the general issue, though, is to work in the reverse direction: add files and make project changes only through QtCreator / in the .pro file and when the project file changes sync Visual Studio by re-generating the .sln file with by opening the .pro file in Visual Studio via Extensions/Qt VS Tools/ Open Qt Project File.

Comment: This works, but the impact of this is that it seems to then force a full rebuild of the project which depending on your project might take some time.